# stm32f3 discovery usart is not sending

Tags: rust, embedded, discovery, usart, stm32f3

Here is my simple register level program written in Rust. This after reading many blogs written in C. I am trying to configure register as they did in C for the discovery board but unfortunately it is not working as expected.

I am trying sending a single character through uart1.
On the hardware side I connect my ftdi module as described in the discovery book.

```
ftdi-----stm32
Rx-------Tx
TX-------rx
gnd-----gnd
```

While sending, the ftdi rx led is blinking indicating data transfer. Mini-com is expected to show this data but it is getting nothing either on ftdi or mini-com.

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

extern crate cortex_m_semihosting;

use cortex_m::asm;
use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use panic_halt as _;
//use stm32f3xx_hal::{pac, prelude::*}; without using hall
use stm32f3::stm32f303;
use cortex_m_semihosting::hprintln;

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {

      let mut peripherals = &stm32f303::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
      let mut rcc = &peripherals.RCC;
      let gpioa = &peripherals.GPIOA;

      let usart1 = &peripherals.USART1;

//selecting and enabling clock for usart1
      rcc.cfgr3.write(|w| w.usart1sw().bits(01)); //slecting clock source as pc_)clock (deefault)
      rcc.apb2enr.write(|w| w.usart1en().set_bit());
//enabling port and pins assign for usart1
      rcc.ahbenr.write(|w| w.iopaen().set_bit());
   
      gpioa.moder.write(|w| w.moder9().bits(10));     // 00 => input, 01 => output, 10 => Alternate function
      gpioa.otyper.write(|w| w.ot9().clear_bit());          //pa10 = rx,  pa9 = tx
      gpioa.ospeedr.write(|w| unsafe {w.ospeedr9().bits(01)});
      
      gpioa.moder.write(|w| w.moder10().bits(10));
      gpioa.otyper.write(|w| w.ot10().clear_bit());
      gpioa.ospeedr.write(|w| unsafe {w.ospeedr10().bits(01)});
   
      gpioa.afrh.write(|w| w.afrh9().af7());    //selecting corrosponding alternate function register
      gpioa.afrh.write(|w| w.afrh10().af7());

      gpioa.pupdr.write(|w| unsafe {w.pupdr9().bits(00)});
      gpioa.pupdr.write(|w| unsafe {w.pupdr10().bits(00)});
// defining the word length
      usart1.cr1.write(|w| w.m().bit8());
// seting baud rate for usart1
      usart1.cr1.write(|w| w.over8().set_bit());
      usart1.brr.write(|w| w.brr().bits(0x47));
// setting numbers of stop bits
      usart1.cr2.write(|w| w.stop().bits(00));
// enableing usart1 and transmission
      usart1.cr1.write(|w|
            w
            .ue().set_bit()
            .te().set_bit());
// wait till transmit data register empty
      while !usart1.isr.read().txe().bit_is_set() {}
// send data
      usart1.tdr.write(|w| w.tdr().bits(u16::from(b'X')));

      
      
      loop {
      while usart1.isr.read().tc().bit_is_clear() {}
      let txe_status = usart1.isr.read().txe().bits(); 
      let value = usart1.tdr.read().tdr().bits() as u8;
      hprintln!("tdr value = {} and txe status = {}", value, txe_status);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that you are using the `write()` method in situations that you might want to be using `modify()`. According to the [svd2rust documentation](https://docs.rs/svd2rust/0.19.0/svd2rust/) (this is what generates the interface for these registers), `write()` will write to the
register using a single store. Any bits you don't explicitly specify will be set to their default values. Therefore, if you `write()` to the same register twice, the second write will overwrite whatever you did with first one.

In contrast, `modify()`, will first read the register, modify the bits as you specify, then write the modified value back. This is probably what you want to do for most of these registers.